# Get value range from MYSQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get all the ages (let's say 18-21) after searching ages 18-21 from the form, but the form is displaying all the data from the database. The username search works though. Any help appreciated.

Here's the form:

```
<?php
return'
<form id="searchForm" action="views/searchResults.php" method="GET">
    <input id="searchBox" placeholder="Search" type="text" name="username" />


<select id="age" name="age">
  <option value="0"> - </option>
  <option value="18-20">18-20</option>
  <option value="20-23">20-23</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="21">21</option>
  <option value="22">22</option>
</select>


<select id="gender" name="gender">
  <option name="nothing" value="0"> - </option>  
  <option name="female" value="female">Female</option>
  <option name="male" value="male">Male</option>
</select>
    <input id="searchButton" type="submit" value="Search" />

</form>';

?>
```

Here's the script for search:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "") or die("Error connecting to database: ".mysql_error());
    /*
        localhost - it's location of the mysql server, usually localhost
        root - your username
        third is your password

        if connection fails it will stop loading the page and display an error
    */

    mysql_select_db("modul8b") or die(mysql_error());
    /* tutorial_search is the name of database we've created */


$username = $_GET['username']; 
$age = $_GET['age']; 
$male = $_GET['gender']; 
$female = $_GET['gender']; 
    // gets value sent over search form

    $min_length = 0;
    // you can set minimum length of the query if you want

    if(strlen($username) >= $min_length){ // if query length is more or equal minimum length then

        $username = htmlspecialchars($username); 
        // changes characters used in html to their equivalents, for example: < to &gt;

        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
        // makes sure nobody uses SQL injection

// Username query does not need a like, you know what the username will be precisely
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE (`username` = '".$username."')");

// You need to filter out an age range
$ages = "";
switch($age)
{
    case 0:
    case 20:
    case 21:
    case 22:
        $ages = $age;
        break;
    case "18-20":
        $ages = "18,19,20";
        break;
    case "20-23":
        $ages = "20,21,22,23";
        break;
}
// combine with ages to get all relevant results
//$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE (`age` in (" . $ages . ") AND gender = '" . $gender . "')");
        if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following



            while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){
            // $results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results) puts data from database into array, while it's valid it does the loop

               echo "<table border='1'>
                <tr>
                <th>username</th>
                <th>gender</th>
                <th>age</th>
                </tr>";
                    {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $results['username'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $results['gender'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $results['age'] . "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                    }
                  echo "</table>";


            }

        }
        else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
            echo "No results";
        }

    }
    else{ // if query length is less than minimum
        echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
    }

?>
```

And here's the table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `age` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  `image` blob NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=24 ;
```

Any help appreciated.Thanks

Comment: LIKE is not the right operator to use for an age. You should be using BETWEEN or > and <. In addition, the age ranges in your <select> element overlap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you are using the deprecated `mysql_` functions, use `PDO` or `mysqli`.  Also, your code as it stands is potentially open to SQL injection.

That aside, you are getting all the results due to the incorrect usage of mysql queries.

For example, a user might enter the following information.

```
No Username
18-20
Male
```

When submitted this will result in

```
// Username not set
@$age = '18-20'; 
@$male = 'male'; 
// Female not set
```

Which will equate to your final query looking something like

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE (`gender` LIKE '%male%' OR `gender` LIKE '%%')
```

As the `%` is a wild card, this will match all records in database.

You need to validate your input and ensure you are running the correct queries.

Try something like

```
// Username query does not need a like, you know what the username will be precisely
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE (`username` = '".$username."')");

// You need to filter out an age range
$ages = "";
switch($age)
{
    case 0:
    case 20:
    case 21:
    case 22:
        $ages = $age;
        break;
    case "18-20":
        $ages = "18,19,20";
        break;
    case "20-23":
        $ages = "20,21,22,23";
        break;
}
// combine with ages to get all relevant results
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE (`age` in (" . $ages . ") AND gender = '" . $gender . "')");
```

Complete Code - **Not Tested**

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "") or die("Error connecting to database: ".mysql_error());
    /*
        localhost - it's location of the mysql server, usually localhost
        root - your username
        third is your password

        if connection fails it will stop loading the page and display an error
    */

    mysql_select_db("modul8b") or die(mysql_error());
    /* tutorial_search is the name of database we've created */


$username = $_GET['username']; 
$age = $_GET['age']; 
$male = $_GET['gender']; 
$female = $_GET['gender'];  
    // gets value sent over search form

    $min_length = 0;
    // you can set minimum length of the query if you want

    if(strlen($username) >= $min_length) { // if query length is more or equal minimum length then

        $username = htmlspecialchars($username); 
        // changes characters used in html to their equivalents, for example: < to &gt;

        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username); 
        // makes sure nobody uses SQL injection

    // Username query does not need a like, you know what the username will be precisely
    $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE (`username` = '".$username."')");
    } else if (strlen($age) > 0 && (strlen($male) > 0 || strlen($female) > 0)) {

    // You need to filter out an age range
    $ages = "";
    switch($age)
    { 
        case 0:
        case 20:
        case 21:
        case 22:
            $ages = $age;
            break;
        case "18-20":
            $ages = "18,19,20";
            break;
        case "20-23":
        $ages = "20,21,22,23";
            break;
    }
    // combine with ages to get all relevant results
    //$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE (`age` in (" . $ages . ") AND gender = '" . $gender . "')");
    } else{ // if query length is less than minimum
        echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
    }

     if(isset($raw_results)) {
        if (mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following



            while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){ 
            // $results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results) puts data from database into array, while it's valid it does the loop

               echo "<table border='1'>
                <tr>
                <th>username</th>
                <th>gender</th>
                <th>age</th>
                </tr>";
                    {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $results['username'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $results['gender'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $results['age'] . "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                    }
                  echo "</table>";


            }

        }
        else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
            echo "No results";
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: it says no results after I submit it. any ideas?

Comment: @user2983295 The code I have added is a sample, it will need to be adopted to your application.  Update your question with the revised code if you still need assistance.

Comment: hey I uploaded the revised code. Can you please take a look?

Comment: @user2983295 you code logic seems to be all over the place. Think about what you are trying to do, and ensure all the conditional statements are correct.  I have updated my answer with some suggestions, but you will need evaluate how to proceed.

Comment: Thanks man. I started from scratch and going to implement your parts. Awesome and helpful, ticked you answer :)!